# Optional route parameters with prefix (angular ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I need to register to a state, a route where the parameters has a prefix and a slash
(route/to/parPrefix1/:paramValue1/parPrefix2/:paramValue2)
and these parameters are all optional, so if the parameter1 is not set, the resulting url should be:
route/to/parPrefix2/value2

How can I handle this case?

Then I have a second issue:
the date should be specified like this: 20/10/2015
If i solve the first point I could set a parameter per date part, however, is there a more elegant solution?

a real case url: /risultati/destinazioni/:destinations/localita/:locations/partenza/:startingDate/ritorno/:returningDate/adulti/:adults/bambini/:children/eta/:childrenAges/aeroporti/:airports/flessibile/:flexDate/

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to set up multiple routes, that point to the same view:

ex:

```
route/to/parPrefix1/:paramValue1
route/to/parPrefix1/:paramValue1/parPrefix2/:paramValue2
```

Comment: what if the missing parameter is the second one? I've up to 9 optional parameters, should I have to register all the permutations?

Comment: After looking over this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108 it looks like you may be able to do something like the following: `/route/to/[parPrefix1/:paramValue1[paraPrefix2/:paramValue2]]`

Comment: I can't make your example work, I red that page, and I think this was just an implementation suggestion..

Comment: Hm ok... Well my only suggestion is be smarter with your URLs to avoid having so many possible routes. Limit it to 2-3 parameters in the URL and the remainder (like date) are in the query string

Answer (score 0):

I agree with spanndemic, see http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters.
Also I think that most of that data should be passed via services or values.
Such a long url will always make things much more difficult.